# Microphone to Airplay

Tags: objective-c, audio, microphone, airplay

Is it possible to stream audio instantly from the microphone in an iphone to an airplay device. I know this can be done with a delay but could it be done instantly with almost no delay.  Basically it needs to stream live audio from microphone to airplay device.

Comment: Did you ever get this working to your liking?

Answer (score 0):

Airplay uses a compressed data stream, and there's always going to be a latency equal to the depth of the buffer being compressed.